# Shakespeare play identification using Naive Bayes in R

Tags: r, naive-bayes

I'm having issues in preparing data in R for use in naiveBayes() where the input are various Shakespeare plays and they need to be matched to the play's genre.

The naiveBayes() basically needs a vector as input that describes each play and and a second vector of equal length containing the category the first data should be categorized as.  One issue is that in the creation on am1, c() collapses

Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ujPwfi3OObTlFlUG9jbjVEM2c/view?usp=sharing

Just to note, I'm still learning R so I'm not sure what a better way is.

```
library('tm')
library('e1071')
library('caTools')
library('rpart')
library('ROCR')
library('randomForest')
library('stringi')

stopwords <- read.csv("data/stopwords.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " ")
c0 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c1.txt")) #comedy block
c1 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c2.txt"))
c2 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c3.txt"))
c3 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c4.txt"))
c4 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c5.txt"))
c5 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c6.txt"))
c6 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c7.txt"))
c7 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c8.txt"))
c8 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c9.txt"))
c9 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/c10.txt"))
t0 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t1.txt")) #tragedy block
t1 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t2.txt"))
t2 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t3.txt"))
t3 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t4.txt"))
t4 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t5.txt"))
t5 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t6.txt"))
t6 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t7.txt"))
t7 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t8.txt"))
t8 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t9.txt"))
t9 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/t10.txt"))
h0 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h1.txt")) #history block
h1 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h2.txt"))
h2 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h3.txt"))
h3 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h4.txt"))
h4 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h5.txt"))
h5 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h6.txt"))
h6 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h7.txt"))
h7 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h8.txt"))
h8 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h9.txt"))
h9 <- stri_flatten(readLines("data/h10.txt"))

smProc <- function (text){
  return (TermDocumentMatrix(tm_map(tm_map(tm_map(tm_map(Corpus(VectorSource(text)), content_transformer(tolower)), removePunctuation), removeNumbers), removeWords, stopwords)))
}

am1 <- c(smProc(c0), smProc(c1), smProc(c2), smProc(c3), smProc(c4), smProc(c5), smProc(c6), smProc(c7), smProc(c8), 
         smProc(t0), smProc(t1), smProc(t2), smProc(t3), smProc(t4), smProc(t5), smProc(t6), smProc(t7), smProc(t8),
         smProc(h0), smProc(h1), smProc(h2), smProc(h3), smProc(h4), smProc(h5), smProc(h6), smProc(h7), smProc(h8)) #All Modification 1

am2 <-  removeSparseTerms(am1, .5)

am3 <- rbind(as.matrix(am2)[,1],as.matrix(am2)[,2],as.matrix(am2)[,3],as.matrix(am2)[,4],as.matrix(am2)[,5],as.matrix(am2)[,6],as.matrix(am2)[,7],as.matrix(am2)[,8],as.matrix(am2)[,9],as.matrix(am2)[,10],as.matrix(am2)[,11],as.matrix(am2)[,12],as.matrix(am2)[,13],as.matrix(am2)[,14],as.matrix(am2)[,15],as.matrix(am2)[,16],as.matrix(am2)[,17],as.matrix(am2)[,18],as.matrix(am2)[,19],as.matrix(am2)[,20],as.matrix(am2)[,21],as.matrix(am2)[,22],as.matrix(am2)[,23],as.matrix(am2)[,24], as.matrix(am2)[,25],as.matrix(am2)[,26], as.matrix(am2)[,27])

ans <- c("comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", "comedy", 
     "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", "tragedy", 
     "history", "history", "history", "history", "history", "history", "history", "history", "history" )

model <- naiveBayes(am3, ans)

#this doesn't work
predict(model, as.matrix(smProc(c9)))
```

Data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ujPwfi3OObTlFlUG9jbjVEM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Be merciful, I'm new at this.

Comment: Well, merciful we will try to be, but you've got to give us something to work from. We can't reproduce this (and thus probably can't help) without access to the text files, so you're making it difficult.

Comment: Ok, let me link them:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ujPwfi3OObTlFlUG9jbjVEM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Rather than sequentially named variables, you'd do much better to use lists, see, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061. This won't solve your modeling problem, but it will streamline your data read-in code to make it shorter and more readable.

Comment: I was able to better navigate the input data and the code above will be edited shortly to reflect changes.